# Exectuing service jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn/.openWnnJAJP

Tags: android

when run my app, it stop and in logs it show" Exectuing service jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn/.openWnnJAJP"
what's mean? who can help me?

Comment: Is this part of an error message?  Is this in logcat or a modal popup?

Comment: yeah, when it appears， the application will  not response -- blank screen

Answer (score 0):

That is the Japanese IME. I think the real problem is that you are running into an out of memory scenario, due to which other services are crashing.